# Delphi - Use SHGetSpecialFolderPath to get My Download folder

Tags: windows, delphi, directory

I am using `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` to retrieve some Windows special folders with Delphi 7. Here is some code sample:

```
const
  CSIDL_DESKTOP    = $0000;
  CSIDL_PERSONAL   = $0005;
  CSIDL_MYPICTURES = $0027;
  CSIDL_MYMUSIC    = $000d;
  CSIDL_MYVIDEO    = $000e;
  CSIDL_WINDOWS    = $0024;
  CSIDL_SYSTEM     = $0025;

function GetSpecialFolderPath(Folder: Integer; ForceDir: Boolean): string;
// Uses ShlObj
var
  Path: array [0..255] of char;
begin
  SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, @Path[0], Folder, ForceDir);
  Result := Path;
end;

edtFolder.Text := GetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_DESKTOP, False);
```

How can I get the "Downloads" folder with this approach?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot get that directory with that API. It predates any OS-designated download folder.

You'll need to use the newer notion of "[known folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776911(v=vs.85).aspx)" with the flag `FOLDERID_Downloads` instead. How to do that has already been answered [elsewhere on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14802473/33732).